# spring log every action by framework

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, log4j

how to log actions happening in the background of spring web application.
i want everything from spring, spring security.

i am not going to any log statements.
By default original spring security source code has logger statements. how to print them to console

Answer (score 0):

> You can use the below logger (uses log4j):

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%p\t%d{ISO8601}\t%r\t%c\t[%t]\t%m%n
```

Comment: can name the dependencies. i was confused by different websites

Comment: log4j >> 1.2.16, spring-security-web >> 3.2.8.RELEASE, spring-security-config >> 3.2.8.RELEASE

Comment: can u paste your code (spring xml) ? also where did you place ur log4j xml ?

Comment: i am using log4j.properties under WEB-INF/classes

Comment: i changed it to above

Comment: Now i am to able to see log statements when i start server. but no logs when moving form one page to anothe page

Comment: I don't think there will be any logs when you move from one page to another.